# Optimal method to speed up Pandas Dataframe groupby aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, multiprocessing

I have a large data frame `price_d` like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| date          monthEndDate  stock  volume  logRet |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 1990-01-01    1990-01-31    A      1       NA     |
| 1990-01-02    1990-01-31    A      2       0.2    |
| 1990-02-01    1990-02-28    A      3       0.3    |
| 1990-02-02    1990-02-28    A      4       0.4    |
| ...           ...                                 |
| 1990-01-01    1990-01-31    B      1       NA     |
| 1990-01-02    1990-01-31    B      2       0.08   |
| ...           ...                                 |
| 1990-02-01    1990-02-28    B      0       0.3    |
| 1990-02-02    1990-02-28    B      3       0.4    |
| ...           ...                                 |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

The length of this dataframe would be in millions, with hundreds of distinct value in `monthEndDate` and thousands of distinct value in `stock`.

I did a groupby aggregation on volume and logRet with three self-defined functions:

```
def varLogRet(_s):
    return pd.Series({'varLogRet': np.var(_s.iloc[_s.to_numpy().nonzero()])})

def TotRet1M(_s):
    return pd.Series({'TotRet1M': np.exp(np.sum(_s))-1})


def avgVolume(_s):
    return pd.Series({'avgVolume': np.mean(_s.iloc[_s.to_numpy().nonzero()])})

return_m = price_d.groupby(['monthEndDate', 'tradingItemId']).agg({'logRet': [varLogRet, TotRet1M],
                                                                       'volume': avgVolume})
```

The groupby aggregation would take serveral minutes. In my case, what's the optimal way to speed up  this process, would multiprocessing work?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this groupby?

Comment: on column logRet, I want the variance of all non-zero elements as well as the exponential of the sum of logRet minus 1, on volume, I want the mean of non-zero elements.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need `.agg` when there are pandas built-in and possibly optimized functions directly available. `NaN`s are ignored by default. Just compute the columns you need separately and make use of them later on.

Benchmark: 8 million rows took less than 3s to complete on my ordinary Core i5-8250U (4C8T) laptop running 64 bit debian 10. The data is a simple repetition from which you provided.

```
# make a dataset of 8 million rows
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=r"\s{2,}")
df2 = df.loc[df.index.repeat(1000000)].reset_index(drop=True)

# set 0's to nan's as requested...
df2[df2["logRet"] == 0] = np.nan

t0 = datetime.now()

dfgp = df2.groupby(['monthEndDate', 'stock'])  # groupby object
# what you want
tot = np.exp(dfgp["logRet"].sum() - 1)
var = dfgp["logRet"].var()  # ddof=1 by default in pandas 1.1.3
vol = dfgp["volume"].mean()

print(f"{(datetime.now() - t0).total_seconds():.2f}s elapsed...")
# 2.89s elapsed...
```

Then you can use these datasets as you wish. e.g. Use `pd.concat([tot, var, vol], axis=1)` to combine them together.

```
tot
Out[6]: 
monthEndDate  stock
1990-01-31    A        inf   <- will not happen with real data
              B        inf
1990-02-28    A        inf
              B        inf
Name: logRet, dtype: float64

var
Out[7]: 
monthEndDate  stock
1990-01-31    A        0.0000
              B        0.0000
1990-02-28    A        0.0025
              B        0.0025
Name: logRet, dtype: float64

vol
Out[8]: 
monthEndDate  stock
1990-01-31    A        1.5
              B        1.5
1990-02-28    A        3.5
              B        1.5
Name: volume, dtype: float64
```

N.B. Overflow on the `tot` part happened simply because of repetitive increment. This will not happen in real data.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for your answer, but I'm not taling about ignore NaNs, but zeros. Like [1,2,3,0], I want a mean of  [1, 2, 3], exclude 0.

Comment: Just set 0's to nan prior to aggregation: `df[df[column] == 0] = np.nan`. This is not the main performance killer.